# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5,4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new in Laravel. I just want to ask if my code is correct. I want to display the the name of the floor and building of the area from a certain assignment in index.blade.php in Collection folder. Collections belong to an Assignment, and Assignments belongs to an Area.

My code in Collection index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($collections as $collection)
  <tr>    
     <td>
         {{ $collection->assignment->area['floor'] }} Floor
         {{ $collection->assignment->area['building'] }}
     </td> 
  <tr>
@endforeach
```

That code generates an error "Trying to get property of non-object". So I'm asking the correct way of displaying it.

Here are the models

Collection.php

```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Assignment::class);
}
```

Assignment.php

```
public function collections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Collection::class);
}
public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
}
```

Area.php

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class);
}
```

CollectionsController.php

```
public function index() //shows the table of the collections
{
    $collections = Collection::all();
    $disposals = Disposal::all();
    return view('collections.index', compact('collections', 'disposals'));
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the data in your controller?

Comment: Please add your controller too

Comment: I just edit the question and add the Collections Controller code

Comment: Why do you want to call the model directly in the view? I mean, you can get all the data in the controller and pass it to the view only for displaying them? Like, in your controller, `$assignments = Assignment::with('collection')->get();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "UPDATE": The problem is from the unclosed tr tag you opened it `<tr><tr>` like this but it should be `<tr></tr>` :D that's it, check the solution and tell me if it works. but look at the bright side, your code is cleaner and more pragmatic now :D

chaining is bad :), try to create a function that gets you the area or else...

or you can use withDefault and return a new instance of the related model

also, your database scheme should look like this:

**collections**

- id
- assignment_id

**assignments**

- id
- area_id

[laravel withDefault doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#default-models)

but for your example I could do:

Collection.php

```
public function assignment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Assignment::class)
        ->withDefault();
}
```

Assignment.php

```
public function collections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Collection::class);
}
public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Area::class)
        ->withDefault();
}
```

Area.php

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class);
}
```

CollectionsController.php

```
public function index() //shows the table of the collections
{
    $collections = Collection::all();
    $disposals = Disposal::all();
    return view('collections.index', compact('collections', 'disposals'));
}
```

also for usage:

```
@foreach ($collections as $collection)
  <tr>    
     <td>
         {{ $collection->assignment->area->floor }} Floor
         {{ $collection->assignment->area->building }}
     </td> 
  <tr/>
@endforeach
```

if everything is ok, and still no result, please check the data itself if it is exists, so check if there is any assignment for the collection, or any area for the assignment returned...

Comment: It doesn't now produce an error but the data of the attributes: floor and building from the area did not display

Comment: Yes the db scheme is right. It does not know produce the error but still didn't display. The data itself is exists, there is an assignment assign in collection and also there is an area for assignment

Comment: ahhhhh, the problem is simplerrr than we thought :D you have unclosed tag

Comment: please close the tr tag with </tr> instead of <tr> :D :D :D

Comment: Iam updating the answer :D

Comment: Yes it works now. I have a question in my controller index, can I do select inner join query for the collections and disposal?

Comment: sorry for the very late reply, i've been working also in another project using C#

Comment: don't worry, and yes you can select inner join query for collections and disposal, but I don't know what is the relation between them. but if the collection has many disposals, you can do Collection::with('disposals')->get()... check the laravel documentation "with".

Comment: yes collections has many disposals. okay I gonna try that one

Comment: one last question, I want to display the collector's name. same also with the area but the relationship between the assignments and collectors is many to many. I had a junction/pivot table called assignment_collector. How I gonna do it? It is a different process?

Answer (score 0):

you should use area like this

```
$collection->assignment()->area()->building
```

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that nearly any part of the following could be returning a `null`:

```
$collection->assignment->area
```

If the relationship from Collection to Assignment doesn't exist for this particular Collection there would be a `null` returned for it.
This would go for all `singular` relationships down the line.

You will need to check for these, figure out how to return some default in the case of `null`, or guarantee that the relationship always exists in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Might be chance like all records doesn't have connected data into subtable in the case error will rise. To overcame error you can use optional() method.

Method will auto handle the null relation.

```
optional($collection->assignment)->area
```

For more information you can check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional)
Good Luck